# Using PHP/MySQL, how do I display all group items by each group?

Tags: php, mysql

The following code lists each of the caritems each line at a time - displaying the carname on each line: (echo mysql_result($result, $i, 'carname') . "  > ";

Instead of displaying the carname on each line, how would I make it so it groups the caritems together by carname and then displays the carname once at the top with each of the caritems associated with that carname displayed below...  It would then move on to the next carname, grouping items...

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars LEFT JOIN caritems ON cars.carid = caritems.carid ORDER BY cars.carsortorder ASC");

    $total_results = mysql_num_rows($result);       


    for ($i = 0; $i < 1500; $i++)

    {

    if ($i == $total_results) { break; }

    $rowid = mysql_result($result, $i, 'caritems.caritemid'); 

    echo mysql_result($result, $i, 'carname') . "&nbsp; > ";

    echo "<div class='carved' />";

    echo "<strong class='caritemheader'>" . mysql_result($result, $i, 'caritemname') . "&nbsp;" . mysql_result($result, $i, 'caritemprice') . "</strong><br />";

    /* CHECK IF BLOB EXISTS AND IF SO DISPLAY IMAGE */

    if (strlen(mysql_result($result, $i, 'caritempicture'))>0) { echo '<br />' . '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode(mysql_result($result, $i, 'caritempicture')) . '"/>' . '<br />'; }

    echo mysql_result($result, $i, 'caritemdescription') . "<br /><br />";

    echo "</div>";

    }
```

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.

Comment: You have to echo the carname and store that information. Then check it during each loop, if it changes you echo out the new one.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Exactly.  As long as your "sort by cars.carsortorder" groups the car names.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic structure using PDO, and trapping unique carnames as others have suggested.  I didn't integrate all of your existing code.

```
try {       
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;charset=utf8", "root", "root");
    $cmd = $db->prepare("
        SELECT * FROM cars 
        LEFT JOIN caritems ON cars.carid = caritems.carid 
        ORDER BY cars.carsortorder ASC;
    ");
    if ($cmd->execute()) {
        $carname = "";
        while ($row = $cmd->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            if ($carname != $row['carname']) {
                echo $row['carname'];
            }
            echo /* everything else */
            $carname = $row['carname'];
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); return; }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can first select distinct **carids** as following:

```
select distinct carid from cars
```

Then in a for loop query every car's items individually as following:

```
select * from caritems where carid=$carid
```

Here **$carid**s are from the first query.

Comment: Why would you run a query over and over when you can get all of the data at once?

Comment: This might be a problem if there are dozens or hundreds of carnames.  Multiple calls to the Database should be avoided.

Comment: Could you possibly utilize my code to demonstrate your solution?  It would be very helpful.

Comment: Else sort by carid asc then keep echoing items as first car while carids are equal. When carid changes it means new car items has started so you can start next cars items separately.

Comment: Could you possibly utilize my code to demonstrate your solution? It would be very helpful.

Comment: Nested queries like this is a terrible anti-pattern and like to kill your database if done in particularly bad cases.